# DynamoDB - Unable to "escape" input

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, xss, aws-sdk

I have a NodeJS app using Express-Js framework and the latest Express-Validator package. I have an input field that I want to "escape" and save the result in AWS DynamoDB.

The parameter is req.body.dealer_code and the value...

```
Before
req.body.dealer_code = "<script>alert('hello')</script>"

After
req.body.dealer_code = "&lt;script&gt;alert(&#x27;hello&#x27;)&lt;&#x2F;script&gt;"
```

When the value is inserted into the DynamoDB, it appears as "<script>alert('hello')</script>" in the Tree view.

What goes wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After an experiment, the string is indeed stored as an escaped string.

```
{ Item:
   { escaped: '&lt;script&gt;alert(&#x27;hello&#x27;)&lt;&#x2F;script&gt;'
   } 
}
```